# Flying fortresses departed from me

Tags: riddle, knowledge, music

Flying fortresses departed to "roam" the Stratosphere from me, but I'm too small to host even a 727.

No one owns my tree, not even me.

I've induced far reaching hysteria and caused the most famous lucid dreams, but mostly only social wasps fear me.

I've hosted a man with sparks and ultramarine women.

**What am I?**

Comment: Should this require particularly specific/unusual trivia-esque knowledge?  Maybe add the knowledge tag?

Comment: @BrentHackers Pop/rock music, perhaps, for some of the references

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Partial but fairly confident answer**

I am pretty sure you are

> Athens, Georgia.

*Flying fortresses departed to "roam" the Stratosphere from me, but I'm too small to host even a 727.*

> [The B-52s](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_B-52s) were formed in Athens, Georgia. The B-52 aircraft for which they are named is also called the Stratofortress. One of their songs is called Roam. Athens has a small airport with short runways; probably too short for a Boeing 727.

*No one owns my tree, not even me.*

> Athens is home to [The Tree That Owns Itself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_That_Owns_Itself). In American law trees cannot literally own themselves.

*I've induced far reaching hysteria and caused the most famous lucid dreams, but mostly only social wasps fear me.*

> Hysteria: [Widespread Panic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Widespread_Panic). Lucid dreams: [Dreams So Real](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dreams_So_Real) though [R.E.M.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R.E.M.) seems kinda relevant too. The social wasps are probably something to do with the Georgia Tech Yellow Jackets -- this has been confirmed by OP, but if it's a reference to some particular match I haven't found it.

*I've hosted a man with sparks and ultramarine women.*

> The man with sparks might be [Mike "Phosphorescent" Houck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorescent_(band)) ... OP says not, but I haven't found better candidates; there are bands called Pylon and Elf Power but those don't seem like improvements. The ultramarine women must be the [Indigo Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indigo_Girls).

Comment: still finding things -- no need to spoonfeed me yet :-)

Comment: I don't think there's any way to spoilerize comments. You can always use something like ROT13 if need be.

Comment: ... OK, I think I've spent as much time as I want to spend right now looking for Sparkly Man and Frightened Hornets :-); feel free to offer some hints for those if you like. (Unless my guess at sparky guy is correct, of course.)

Comment: I would never have got this, so thanks for taking up the baton :-)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I see, thanks for the info on spoilierizing. Regarding the part that you wrote you're still missing you're correct about the social wasps and regarding the man with sparks it would be a musician from a different genre. Oh, and regarding the lucid dreams I was actually thinking of the 2nd possibility that you mentioned, though the first one you thought of seems to fit equally well.

Answer (score 2):

Could you be

> Hollywood?

*Flying fortresses departed from me, but I'm too small to host even a 727.*

> Apparently there's a US film called [*Flying Fortress*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortress_(2012_film)), but a Boeing 727 wouldn't fit into the studio.

*No one owns my tree, not even me.*

> Perhaps a reference to the fact that "holly wood" sounds like a tree?

*I've induced far reaching hysteria and caused the most famous lucid dreams, but mostly only social wasps fear me.*

> Presumably these are all film references. The "lucid dreams" thing must be [*Inception*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inception), but I'm not sure about the other two.

*I've hosted a man that sparkles and ultramarine women.*

> [Twilight vampires](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Twilight_characters#Vampires) and [Marvel's Mystique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mystique_(comics)#Film).
>
>  [image: Edward Cullen]  [image: Mystique]

Comment: Very interesting. This wasn't my intended answer but I am up voting.

Comment: I made some tweaks to the wording of the riddle